# problem with the scope resolution operator in older code from tutorial

Tags: c++, scope, operator-keyword, resolution

I am going trough a Linkedin learning couse called Game_programing_2 and Visual Studio is giving me the following error **"qualified name is not allowed in member declaration"** in the tutorial code Bob::Bob().
Here is the .h file from the tutorial files (not my code)

```
#include "PlayableCharacter.h"

class Bob :public PlayableCharacter {
public:
    Bob::Bob();
    bool virtual handleInput();
};
```

It seems Visual Studio wants me to do this

```
#include "PlayableCharacter.h"

class Bob :public PlayableCharacter {
public:
    Bob();
    bool virtual handleInput();
};
```

It seems to work, but since I am learning I would like to know if the two pieces of code are the same and if so why the syntax has changed.
I have seached trough the web and the only answer I could find is that it maybe has something to do with the version of C++.
Since this code is from a tutorial it must have worked at some point with Bob::Bob().
Hope someone here can explain it to me, so I can learn to code properly:)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. So you are using C++ or C#? Remember, the **tags** attract the right audience to your question, so if you use irrelevant tags you get the wrong audience and the audience you want don't see that question

Comment: Right did not think to add this to tags.
Thank you